# Query AD from sql server 2008 Description field gives error

Tags: sql-server-2008, active-directory, ldap, adsi

I am trying to query the Active Directory with the following SQL query, which works perfectly.

```
SELECT * FROM OpenQuery(ADSI, 
                         'SELECT title, displayName, sAMAccountName, givenName, 
                                 telephoneNumber, facsimileTelephoneNumber, sn,  
                                 mail, physicalDeliveryOfficeName
                          FROM ''LDAP://DC=mydomain,DC=org'' 
                          WHERE sAMAccountName = ''myUser''')
```

When I add the `description` attribute I get the following error:

> Msg 7346, Level 16, State 2, Line 6
>   Cannot get the data of the row
>   from the OLE DB provider "ADSDSOObject" for linked server "ADSI".
>   Could not convert the data value due to reasons other than sign
>   mismatch or overflow.

Answer (score 4):

The SQL/ADO query capabilities into Active Directory are very limited - I would try to avoid using them if ever possible.

The reason here is that the `description` attribute in Active Directory is multi-valued - it could potentially contain multiple values (something that's impossible in a relational database model).

Therefore, the SQL/ADO query provider **cannot** read any of those multi-valued attributes from LDAP - there's no way or option or checkbox to enable that - it's just not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem getting the `Description` field from AD while attempting to use `ADsDSOObject` and `ADO`.

you have to inter-ate through the values with a `For Each` or `Do until ... EOF` type of statement.

[Here is a good example](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/Scripting/microsoft.public.scripting.vbscript/2006-12/msg00200.html)